# how to find request parameters in 'nodejs'

Tags: node.js, httpwebrequest

when i sent a request to nodejs server,

how can we find the parameters sent in the request query when request sent to nodejs server.

```
req.param

req.params

req.query
```

all giving undefined.

also when i `stringify` `req` request it gives error :

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

How to find query parameters.

Comment: What kind of request? `req.body` contains the body (data) for POST requests.

Comment: here i am talking about get request for first

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [url](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module:

```
$ npm install url
```

And then something like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true); // true to get query as object
  var queryAsObject = parsedUrl.query;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(queryAsObject));

  res.end(JSON.stringify(queryAsObject));

}).listen(8080);

console.log("Server listening on port 8080");
```

Test in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/?a=123&b=xxy
```

For POST requests you can use [bodyParser](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser).

Comment: url is deprecated since node 11, you should use `new URL`

Answer (score 0):

Since `url.parse()` is [deprecated](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/50632#issuecomment-1806814395) and `new URL()` does not accept relative links, here is what we are supposed to use nowadays I assume:

<sub>/api/some-action?param1=foo&param2=bar</sub>

```js
const { pathname, searchParams } = new URL(req.url!, "x://x");
const param1 = searchParams.get("param1");
const param2 = searchParams.get("param2");
```

`"x://x"` is just a dummy base url to make new `URL()` work for a relative url which [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#messageurl) is.